# How to implement binding throttling in Kendo UI?

Tags: kendo-ui, throttling

Could you provide an example of [throttling](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html) implementation in Kendo UI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the Google search record, Kendo UI now includes a built-in throttle method. It can be used to limit the number of calls to a function within a specified time.

Example usage from the Kendo UI docs:

```
  var throttled = kendo.throttle(function() {
      console.log("hey! " + new Date());
  }, 100);

  // will log two times "hey":
  // (1) once for the first call
  // (2) once for the last call, roughly 100ms after the first one
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      throttled();
  }
```

Docs: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo#methods-throttle

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [jquery-throttle-debounce](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/docs/files/jquery-ba-throttle-debounce-js.html#jQuery.throttle) library. Here's some snippets of integrating it with Kendo databinding, assuming before you had `keyup: updateFromDataSource`.

```
<input id="searchText" type="text" data-value-update="keyup" data-bind="value: searchTextVal, events: { keyup: searchTextKeyed  }"  />

searchTextKeyed: jQuery.debounce(300, function () { this.updateFromDataSource(); }), ...
```